# How to parenthesized the following php line?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I really don't have any knowledge of PHP and after searching stack overflow for the same error, I couldn't find the solution by myself (I know the solution is the error, but I don't know where to put the brackets). This error is taken my website down.

> Fatal error: Unparenthesized a ? b : c ? d : e is not supported. Use
> either (a ? b : c) ? d : e or a ? b : (c ? d : e) in
> /var/www/vhosts/[domain]/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/avada-functions.php
> on line 443.

**Line 443 is:**

```
$items .= '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="' . esc_url( ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) ? esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) : isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) : '' ) . '">';
```

Comment: That's not something that we can tell you, where the parentheses go depends on the order in which the expressions should be evaluated. Alternatively, check if there's an updated version of the theme with this bug fixed, or a ticket about it with a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in this case is using nested ternary operators. The error says that you should clearly define in parentheses which elements belong to which expression.

The additional parentheses in your code should be placed around the following expression

```
(isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) : '')
```

so your line should look like this

```
$items .= '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="' . esc_url( ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) ? esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) : (isset( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ? esc_url_raw( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) : '') ) . '">';
```

Instead, I suggest a different approach - break this line into simpler elements, like this way

```
$ternaryTrue = esc_url_raw(wp_unslash($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
$ternatyFalse = isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? esc_url_raw(wp_unslash($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) : '';
$value = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $ternaryTrue : $ternatyFalse;
$items .= '<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="' . esc_url($value) . '">';
```